# Ошибки в коде дискорд бота

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот

Показывает 6 ошибок но почему он их показывает у меня не получается понять не подскажете ли в чем здесь проблема?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require('fs');
let config = require('./botconfig.json');
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix;

fs.readdir('./cmds/'(err,files))=>{
  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfiles = files.filter(f => 
});
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Бот запустился  ${bot.user.username}!`);
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
  if(Message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type == "dm" ) return;
  let user = message.author.username;
  let userid = message.author.id;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let command = messageArray[0].toLoserCase();
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  if(message.content.starWith(prefix)) return;
  let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Укажите в вопросе какие ошибки возникают.

Comment: ';' expected. ts(1005) [9, 33]
Expression expected ts (1109) [12, 1]
Declaration or statement expected ts(1128) [12, 2]

Comment: Ну так Вы посмотрите внимательно на указанные строчки (или строчкой выше). Совсем-совсем ничего не смущает?

Comment: решил почти все проблемы, но с последней что то не выходит 
fs.readdir('./cmds/',(err,files) =>
{
  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfiles = files.filter(f) => - вот здесь пишет ';' expected.ts(1005)
});
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Бот запустился  ${bot.user.username}!`);
});

Comment: А что, по-Вашему, должна делать эта строчка? `let jsfiles = files.filter(f) =>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка была в этом фрагменте:

```
 fs.readdir('./cmds/'(err,files))=>{
      if(err) console.log(err);
      let jsfiles = files.filter(f => 
    });
```

Точнее в строчке `let jsfiles = files.filter(f =>)` я просто не дописал код полностью и из-за этого я не мог исправить ошибку
Остальные ошибки были из-за моей не внимательности.. где то ; не поставил где то неверно поставил другие знаки 
Спасибо всем кто решил мне помочь и тыкнул пальцем в ошибку которую я в дальнейшем исправил